# Display all registered users information

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display all register users information to the site so visitors can check info about users who is registered.
how to do this ? but without any plugins..

Comment: is there any restriction of role ... means (administrator, subscriber ...) or get all

Comment: yes, only subscribers info will be display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [get_users()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Here is example

```
$user_args = array(
     'role' => 'subscribers',
     'orderby' => 'nicename'
);

$users_list = get_users($user_args);

foreach($users_list as $users) {
    echo $users->display_name;

    // if you want to show meta values
    echo get_user_meta($users->ID, 'Meta Key Name', true);
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: its my pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-user-listing/

With this plugin you can retrieve users by using a shortcode

```
[userlist]
```

You can also give it parameters to retrieve users by roles:

```
[userlist role="author" number="5"]
```

Let me know if it helped, good luck.

For all the parameters you can see :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-user-listing/faq/